# Can the Gate spell draw a creature larger that 20 feet in every dimension through the portal it creates?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, portals

The [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) spell says:

> When you cast this spell, you can speak the name of a specific creature (a pseudonym, title, or nickname doesn't work). If that creature is on a plane other than the one you are on, the portal opens in the named creature's immediate vicinity and draws the creature through it to the nearest unoccupied space on your side of the portal. [...]

However, the size of the summoned portal is

> 5 to 20 feet in diameter.

What happens if you speak the name of a creature larger than 20 feet in diameter?

Answer (score 16):

## The rules are ambiguous

Here are two possible interpretations. Since there are two, you'll have to ask your GM whether this will work:

### The creature is drawn through regardless of size

Spells [do what they say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107637/41726), and **no size limitation** is placed on the "drawing through" effect of the spell. Whether or not the creature could fit through the *gate* normally, it is drawn through by this effect.

> the portal opens in the named creature's immediate vicinity and draws the creature through it to the nearest unoccupied space on your side of the portal

If the spell could only draw through creatures that fit in a space equal in dimensions to the diameter of the portal, it would say so. Since it does not, this effect is not bound by the size of the creature.

*Side-note: If you want a narrative explanation, most gargantuan creatures [can squeeze](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#SqueezingintoaSmallerSpace) through a space that huge creatures fit in (a condition that a 20 foot portal satisfies)*

### The creature can only be drawn through if it fits into the portal.

Since the spell specifies that the maximum portal size is:

> 20 feet in diameter.

Any creature that cannot fit will fail to be drawn through since you...

> can't pull a creature through a hole that it doesn't fit through.
>
> [credit to [NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148165/41726)]

Determining whether a creature can fit through the portal is an issue that NautArch's answer explores in a bit more detail. It's another question you will have to ask your GM as some creatures are too large to sensibly squeeze through a 20 foot hole (even though they are classified as gargantuan).

Comment: I think I agree with your answer, but wonder if your statement "If the spell could only draw through creatures that fit in a space equal in dimensions to the diameter of the portal, it would say so."  might require some clarification re: "Travel through the portal is possible only by *moving through its front.*"  Does "through" perhaps imply that a creature must fit *through* the hole?

Answer (score 8):

## It's a bit up to the DM as dimensions may differ from size category

How does the [Gate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) spell (PHB, 244) work?

The spell begins with a description of the size of the portal it opens (emphasis mine):

> You conjure a portal linking an unoccupied space you can see within range to a precise location on a different plane of existence. **The portal is a circular opening, which you can make 5 to 20 feet in diameter.**

It then goes into what happens when you summon a creature whose name is known:

> When you cast this spell, you can speak the name of a specific creature (a pseudonym, title, or nickname doesn't work). If that creature is on a plane other than the one you are on, the **portal opens in the named creature's immediate vicinity and draws the creature through it** to the nearest unoccupied space on your side of the portal.

While it doesn't specifically state that the size of the portal matters, it makes sense that the portal size is a limiting factor in what can go through it. You can't pull a creature through a hole that it doesn't fit through.

But that's where the Squeezing rules may come into play. The [squeezing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#CreatureSize) rules are explained very well and state that a Gargantuan creature (the largest size category) should be able to squeeze into the space when looking at the rules regarding creature size categories and the space they control. A Gargantuan can squeeze into a 15x15 space per those rules, but for creatures whose dimensions are listed, it isn't unreasonable to consider that with regard to the portal size.

We can look at the actual dimensions of the creature with regard to the portal size, and we'll use the Tarrasque as an example (MM, 286):

> A scaly biped, the tarrasque is fifty feet tall and seventy feet long, weighing hundreds of tons.

That's a fairly big creature to fit into a 20' diameter hole.

While creature sizes are based more on areas of control, the rules on squeezing utilize those sizes. There does seem RAW support for both Yes(gargantuan size can squeeze through 20' spaces) and No(the listed overall dimensions are much larger and it doesn't make sense), and I'd leave it up to a DM as to how they adjudicate size descriptions vs size categories at their table to decide.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93730/discussion-between-david-coffron-and-nautarch).

Comment: "It doesn't make sense" is a very valid reason for your DM to say no.

Comment: @valkor to be clear, it's not just about making sense (this is fantasy after all), but the issue of dimensions and not just size categories.

Comment: "I summon the tarrasque!" "The portal opens and... a mighty paw comes through. The rest of the beast appears trapped on the other side."

Comment: How gently is it drawn through? How sharp are the edges? "I summon the tarrasque!" "The portal opens and... hundreds of tons of dismembered meat, broken bones, and scales are pulled through." So much for the tarrasque.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I think allowing this spell to auto-kill creatures above a certain size would be a very problematic ruling at many tables.

Answer (score -3):

While I've considered this as well since the idea of summoning something like the Tarrasque to siege a city sounds awesome, I then realized the Gate has those dimensions. If I were DMing, I'd probably limit the spell to creatures that could fit or squeeze through those dimensions.

However, if the players really wanted to, I might say that they could attempt to **find** and **convince** enough powerful Wizards who can all learn the Gate spell (if they don't already know it) and all simultaneously cast Gate. And as long as they're all naming the same creature, the Gate's size is multiplied by the number of Wizards.

You might also require them to create an actual structure to contain the Gate as that much arcane power in a singular area would be far too unstable (think the Dark Portal from Warcraft). Basically it would take tens of thousands (if not hundreds of thousands) of gold and a year of more of planning and construction to pull off such a feat, and if that's what they truly wanted to pursue I would design their future adventures in the campaign around that end.

Comment: You've stipulated a lot of DM adjudication as well as custom rules, which is fine but it's unclear if you've actually done this yourself and how it worked. Furthermore, I'm unclear on the mechanics by which this method would function (i.e. 'the Gate's size is multiplied by the number of Wizards' - this makes me want to inquire about what dimensions are being multiplied).